# if I install 23.04 now can I upgrade it easily to 23.10 next month (Ubuntu)

Tags: upgrade, 23.04

I started downloading the 23.04 iso and realized quarter tiling is on 23.10.

So I have a choice now between 22.04.04 LTS and 23.04.

Wouldn't mind trying 23.04 if I can upgrade next month to 23.10 easily.

Comment: Please note:  Ubuntu *development* releases are not supported on sites such as this, so do consider that. The upgrade path is identical to normal *release-upgrade*, except the `-d` is used to allow upgrading to the *development* release.  If you look, almost all release notes are now written (*beta* is this coming thursday, where release notes as expected for the beta release) so instructions are there if you look (*some won't be published/visible yet publicly*)

Comment: My prior comment isn't what you asked sorry; ie. you can upgrade to *mantic* **now** which is what my prior comment is about (*sorry it was out-of-place*), but upgrading next month is **fully supported** and expected. You won't be able to *release-upgrade* on the day of release; as the Ubuntu Release team will need to open the upgrade path (except using the `-d` option I covered in prior comment), which is normally done in the week after release (*5-6 days after release, given release is thursday*) but it may also be delayed if problems are known (*ensuring stability for users*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, upgrading from 23.04 to 23.10 is a supported upgrade path.

Comment: I CV'd the main question as a duplicate of the canonical question if you want to review it.